# Unmarshalling JSON to certain type (string) always

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have some JSON that can have either a number or a string as the first element.  I always want to be able to store this as a string value but instead I get a crash as it is reading it as quite rightly so a number type.

I tried to force the unmarshalling as a string but this was not successful.

```
string `json:",string"`
```

I am following this [guide](http://eagain.net/articles/go-json-array-to-struct/) which seems to fit my data nicely.

How can I always get this element at [0] to always read and save as a string?

Code & Playground below...

https://play.golang.org/p/KP4_1xPJiZ

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "encoding/json"

const inputWorking = `
["AAAAAA", {"testcode" : "Sss"}, 66666666]
`

const inputBroken = `
[111111, {"testcode" : "Sss"}, 66666666]
`

type RawMessage struct {
    AlwaysString        string `json:",string"`
    ClientData    ClientData
    ReceptionTime int
}

type ClientData struct {
    testcode string
}

func main() {

    var n RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputWorking), &n); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", n)

    var o RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputBroken), &o); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", o)
}

func (n *RawMessage) UnmarshalJSON(buf []byte) error {
    tmp := []interface{}{&n.AlwaysString, &n.ClientData, &n.ReceptionTime}
    wantLen := len(tmp)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if g, e := len(tmp), wantLen; g != e {
        return fmt.Errorf("wrong number of fields in RawMessage: %d != %d", g, e)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a universal receiver, i.e. of interface type, and then do a type assertion:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type RawMessage struct {
    UnknownType interface{} `json:"unknown_type"`
}

const inputString = `{"unknown_type" : "a"}`

const inputFloat = `{"unknown_type" : 123}` // Note: Unmarshals into a float64 by default!!!

func main() {

    var n RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputFloat), &n); err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
    }

    switch v := n.UnknownType.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("Received a string: %v", v)
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("Received a number: %v", v)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("Unknown type: %v", v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes of course! So something like...https://play.golang.org/p/Yb0I7X7Z_5 and whenever I read the value I make sure I check it?

Comment: @LeeArmstrong, yes - you get it into interface{} and then assert wether its a string or a _number_. Keep in mind that Go won't differentiate between ints and floats on receive, it will just give you float64 for everything. So you may also need to convert to int if required.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and so far the best I found was to make a type from string with a custom unmarshaller:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// Stringish exists because api send back integers unquoted even if underlying type is string
type StringIsh string

func (f *StringIsh) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {

    var receiver string
    if len(data) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    if data[0] != '"' {
        quoted := strconv.Quote(string(data))
        data = []byte(quoted)
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &receiver); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *f = StringIsh(receiver)
    return nil

}

type Test struct {
    Foo StringIsh
}

func main() {
    dest := &Test{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"foo": "bar"}`), &dest)
    fmt.Println(dest)

    dest = &Test{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"foo": 123}`), &dest)
    fmt.Println(dest)
}
```

Try it yourself at https://goplay.space/#i0OVs9tnule

Answer (score -1):

Try this if it resolve this issue, make a generic interface as user input is not defined

```
interface{} `json:",string"`
```

package main

```
import "fmt"
import "log"
import "encoding/json"

const inputWorking = `
["AAAAAA", {"testcode" : "Sss"}, 66666666]
`

const inputBroken = `
[111111, {"testcode" : "Sss"}, 66666666]
`

type RawMessage struct {
    AlwaysString        interface{} `json:",string"`
    ClientData    ClientData
    ReceptionTime int
}

type ClientData struct {
    testcode string
}

func main() {

    var n RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputWorking), &n); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", n)

    var o RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputBroken), &o); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: This is no different to above and it doesn't save as a string